# Error Explanation

Tags: android, multithreading, error-handling

This is the Error I have:

```
    08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.database_demo/com.database_demo.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.database_demo.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:92)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     ... 11 more
```

What I was able to make out about these Errors is that they are because of using networking related tasks within the `OnCreate()` method! am I correct or there may be more reasons to it?

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.database_demo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />      
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <!-- Control Database connection -->
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Database_demo"
                  android:label="Login"></activity>
        <!--  DashBoard Activity -->
        <activity
            android:label="Dash Board" 
            android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: you have to register your activity in Manifest.xml file

Comment: I have done it already

Comment: @geet  I posted the manifest take a look

Comment: `08-07 13:50:31.175: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.database_demo.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:92)` Can you show line 92 and full LoginActivity class ?

Comment: Loaded the LoginActivity please see it

Comment: your manifest is right. It opens your LoginActivity But some where its component or object is null.That's why you get ComponentInfo...Error. Can you show us whats on line 92 of LoginActivity?

Comment: I got the Problem its because of that  'btnLinkToRegister' BUTTON click event wherein I have an intent that is intending to start the respective activity itself, commented out the this OnClick and the app loads with NO errors

Comment: Please do not change a question entirely.  Some of the answers and comments are really confusing since they refer to your original problem which you have now edited to a completely different error.  One question per error or problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to create Object for  `Button btnLinkToRegister;`

```
btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't updated your mainfest file, add the folowing line to AndroidManifest.xml and it should work fine.

```
<activity android:name="com.database_demo.LoginActivity" />
```

Comment: I had the activity name written wrongly while changing things to get away with error now I have made the name correct and updated the LOGCAT details above (THE LOGCAT NOW SHOWS THE REAL ERROR)